# Layout weightSum not working Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a layout with a Parent LinearLayout with weightSum of 100 and two child layouts with `weights` 40 and 60.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/cv_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_weight="40">
        <Droid.SquareImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imgPlaceholderImage"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
        <Droid.CustomTextView
            android:text="Category"
            app:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:color="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/txtCategory"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:ellipsize="end" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <Droid.CustomTextView
            android:text=""
            app:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:color="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle" />
        <Droid.CustomTextView
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:color="#d5d5d5"
            android:id="@+id/txtDate" />
        <Droid.CustomTextView
            android:text=""
            app:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:color="@android:color/black"
            android:id="@+id/txtDetail"
            android:maxEms="4"
            android:ellipsize="end" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

With this I get the layout as so :-
[image]

My second row looks fine, but the first one looks weird. Iam using a `RecyclerView`. 
**How can I make my first row look like the second one?**

Comment: try to replace relative layout with linear layout

Comment: Just set 0dp width to RelativeLayout....

Comment: and also use adjustviewbounds attribute in squareimageview.if the custom squareview had this attribute.and remove scaletype attribute

Comment: @Awadesh I tried doing tha but it gives the same result

Comment: Make the two siblings inside your parent linearlayout as linearlayouts with "horizontal orientation" and assign weights to them. This will place them propotionately

Comment: @cafebabe1991 I want the second layout to have vertical orientation

Comment: @HareshChhelana Tried it and gives same result. Also My second row looks fine with the same layout

Comment: @Vishwa It didnt work and my second row looks fine with my layout above. Its just the problem with first row

Comment: See this representation i made, this is what you need to do
https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/172u8X2zhyqBhDLLyVi3EbxzOqByMCPDWokWHtZlN6TE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @helloworld did u try to make relativelayout width as 0dip and use default imageView instead of squareimageview.So that you can get an idea on whats wrong with it..

Comment: @cafebabe1991.  I dont want to divide my parent linearlayout into two smaller horiontal layouts. Its a simple layout with one parent horizontal layout with two layouts with 40:60 ratio. Its a row for a recycler view which gets inflated. So In my image the second row is the same layout inflated on the second position

Comment: try below solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/35238014/2826147 @helloworld

Comment: Inside the Parent LinearLayout, replace first child (RelativeLayout) "android:layout_width="match_parent"" to "android:layout_width="0dp""

Answer (score 1):

Try to `0dp` width to `RelativeLayout` and whenever you have used `weight` properties to any `layout` or `views` you have to set `width` or `height` `0dp` on respective of parent `layout` `orientation` like if parent layout is `horizontal` then set `width` `0dp` or if parent layout is `vertical` then set `height` `0dp`.

You not required given `weightSum` 100 to any `layout` or `view` which by default considering `weightSum` 100.

Answer (score 0):

You must set value of `width` to `0dp` for `RelativeLayout` and then weight will work.
in your case because you have used a horizontal `LinearLayout` you must change the `width` of `RelativeLayout` to `0dp`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:id="@+id/cv_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="150dp"
android:weightSum="100"
android:background="@android:color/white">
<RelativeLayout
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_weight="40">
    <Droid.SquareImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imgPlaceholderImage"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    <Droid.CustomTextView
        android:text="Category"
        app:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:color="@android:color/white"
        android:id="@+id/txtCategory"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="end" />
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_weight="60"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <Droid.CustomTextView
        android:text=""
        app:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:color="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle" />
    <Droid.CustomTextView
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:color="#d5d5d5"
        android:id="@+id/txtDate" />
    <Droid.CustomTextView
        android:text=""
        app:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:color="@android:color/black"
        android:id="@+id/txtDetail"
        android:maxEms="4"
        android:ellipsize="end" />
</LinearLayout>
```

To learn more about how Layout_weight works please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3996044/2101822) .

Comment: I tried doing this and it gives the same result. Notice that the second row has the same layout but it looks exactly like I want unlike the first row

Comment: I guess its because you have a custom image view with android:layout_width="match_parent" in your RelativeLayout.

Comment: So is there a solution for this? Im confused as the second row of the list has the same layout but still looks fine

Comment: I think something wrong with imageView size. you have different image view sizes.

Comment: The Images sizes are different for sure. But shouldnt the ImageView be restricted to match the parent and take only 40% of the screen irrespective of the image size?

Comment: No it does not because you've set the image view width to match_parent it does not allow its parent(RelativeLayout) to take 40% of it's parent(LinearLayout)

Comment: layout_weight specifies how much of the "extra" space in the layout to be allocated to the View.

Answer (score 0):

check this solution, will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cv_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <Droid.SquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPlaceholderImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

        <Droid.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCategory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:color="@android:color/white"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Category"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            app:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <Droid.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:color="@android:color/black"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf" />

        <Droid.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:color="#d5d5d5"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf" />

        <Droid.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDetail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:color="@android:color/black"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxEms="4"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:customFont="Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have already tried using LinearLayout instead of Relative and it does not work

Comment: I have done with weightSum which was not working on your side. Try this solution in your xml file @helloworld

Comment: Nope. This is a layout which I had in place initially.

Comment: the image you have shown , this answer is according to that now what changes you want to make(what you want to achieve). please elaborate or show some screenshot @helloworld